# Can MS Graph Webhook can only invoke public API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Implementing a service that will get notified when a mailbox receives an email. Created the subscription fine but it will only receive mails when the API gateway created is set to regional on AWS making it public.

This seems odd to me that there is no way to configure the webhook with oauth details rather than leaving the api open.

Can't see anything in the docs regarding this, would also be interested to hear what others are doing to tackle this issue..

Thanks

Comment: With Azure i tried the above and it works for me. I can able to setup the webhook, notifies when a mailbox receives an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and a question i posted to Microsoft here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/406 it seems the only way to use a non public notification URL is by using Azure Event Hubs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery

Also there is an alternative workaround to keep your endpoint public but create a resource policy to only accept traffic from the Microsoft IP addresses listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/additional-office365-ip-addresses-and-urls?view=o365-worldwide (see the "Microsoft Graph Change Notifications" entry)